# How to execute JavaScript after a page is transitioned with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When a page do a transition to another (and use the `location.hash` stuff) , this second page does not load any JavaScript. How can I execute JavaScript when a page is loaded (if this one "comes" from a transition from its parent) ?

I have page1.html, with a link to page2.html. This page2.html loads with a transition (slide effect by default).

In page2.html no JavaScript is executed. I tried with a simple

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("x");
</script>
```

but does not work. I tried with a lot of `document.ready`, `bind`, `live`, `oncreate`, `pagecreate`, and so on.

Comment: Can you shed a little more light on what you are trying to do?  If this is an HTML matter, are you writing the HTML by hand or are you generating it dynamically.  If the latter, what language are you going to use?

Comment: I edited the question with more information

Answer (score 9):

You could use a callback function. After the animation call a function.

in jQuery:

```
$('#yourElement').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete. add your callback logic here
});
```

If using Webkit transitions:

```
$('#yourElement').addEventListener(
 'webkitTransitionEnd',
 function( event ) {
     // Animation complete. add your callback logic here
 }, false );
```

And if using jQuery Mobile, it appears you can use the 'pageshow' and 'pagehide' event listeners:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});

$('div').live('pagehide',function(event, ui){
  alert('This page was just shown: '+ ui.nextPage);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't handle the animation. The transition between pages in jQueryMobile is hardcoded.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the jQM documentation that mentions the pageshow event. Looks like that should be what you need.

Comment: Thanks DA, but it's not working ... that events are called before initializePage() event ... I checked the original source code ... I'll write to developers to put a "oncomplete" optional in that "real last" event ... thank you anyway

Comment: hmm...looks like a similar problem here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/apply-markup-enhancements-after-page-is-loaded not sure if it's applicable to you, but maybe it helps.

Comment: hmmm that's just for list views  ... but thanx !

Comment: do report back if you find a solution. I'm curious myself.

Answer (score 9):

Basically in Jquerymobile when you do a page transition only the content inside

```
    <div data-role="page">
    ...
    </div>
```

gets changed so effectively all your scripts and everything you have included in

```
    <head></head>
```

tags is not getting loaded.

So to solve this you need to include your script inside the page, like below

```
    <div data-role="page">
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
    </div>
```

Thanks,
Dinesh Parne

Comment: Loading a .js file via script tag will work but this requires a separate file for each page that calls for script.  Not only is this quite clunky for the common case when you only need a few lines of initialization code for each page, but it will generally suffer from cache issues, i.e. the script for the page will only execute the first time the page is visited.

Answer (score 3):

Also this issue seems to be highlighted here:
[jquerymobile - include .js and .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643661/jquerymobile-include-js-and-html)

I've had success by having ALL the JavaScript located/included on the very first page, and for each linked page I have wrapped the code inside a block like this:

```
$('#page2').live('pageshow',function(){

   //page twos JS                  
});

$('#page3').live('pageshow',function(){

   //page threes JS                  
});
```

And of course each document must include the usual container with the corresponding id:

```
<section id="page2" data-role="page" data-theme="a"> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to doing this
1.) Add all script files in very first page
2.) Whenever calls new page You use link rel="external" (eg `<a href="#demo" rel="external">Next Page</a>`)
when doing this then the next page will execute its header section

But first 1 is best in most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `rel="external"` is that it means any JQuery Mobile page transitions won't work....

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of same problem, if you are using  tag for transition Try adding `target="_self"` attribute to it. It kind of worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
function pageEngine(event, ui)
{
  // this is the page change engine.  It makes sure the appropriate
  // javascript files get loaded and the page init function gets called
  console.log("pageEngine: " +ui.toPage[0].id);

  // ui.toPage[0].id = the id in the data-role="page" 
  // <div id="debugPage" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  switch(ui.toPage[0].id)
  {            
    case "homePage":
          homePageReady();    // reinit the home page - i.e. update unreads
       break;

    case "mapPage":
      $.getScript("js/map.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
          onMapPageReady();
      }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) { jsLoadError(xhr, textStatus, error, "map.js"); });
      break;

    case "thirdPage":
      // do nothing as this page requires no .js
      break;

    default:
      console.log("page not found: " +ui.toPage[0].id);
  }
}
```

The pageEngine() gets called from a little function tied to window.onload like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
  console.log("window.onload: " +timeStamp());
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    if(typeof ui.toPage == "undefined" || typeof ui.toPage[0] == "undefined")
    {
      // during startup and app init there are a lot of these
      console.log("toPage[0] is undefined");
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("pagecontainerbeforeshow: " +ui.toPage[0].id);
    }
    pageEngine(event, ui);
  });  
}
</script>
```

The above gets set AFTER jquery is loaded but BEFORE jquery.mobile is loaded.