# How do I check if a jQuery mobile has finished transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a page property or a method that I can use to check if the current active page has finished loading or has finished transitions?

Comment: you can use a callback or listener, kind of what this question asks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332772/how-to-execute-javascript-after-a-page-is-transitioned-with-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 2):

pagechange event.

> *This event is triggered after the changePage() request has finished loading the page into the DOM and all page transition animations have completed.*

More info: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

```
$('#page').bind( "pagechange", function( e, data ) {
    alert("pagechange");   
});
```

Comment: Check-out all the page-events, there are ones for loading external document specifically (which may work better to find if a page has finished `loading`). http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html